# HTML image 'onclick' redirects to another page when calling javascript function (unwanted)

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an HTML image which I want to click, which will trigger a javascript function to be called, which will make some changes to the page based on a ruby-generated `collection_select`. But whenever I try to call the function it **redirects to another page** `(pages\main.html.erb)`, which is not what I want.

html image (and related code):

```
<%= f.collection_select :id,
    Customer.where(business_id: current_customer.business_id),
    :id,
    :full_name,
     { prompt: 'Select' },
     { id: "colleage-select", onChange: "renderColCal(this)" } %>

<input type="image" src="http://..." onclick="addParticipant()">

 ....

<p>Meeting Participants:</p>
 <ol id ="list">

 </ol>
```

javascript:

```
//application.js

var List = document.getElementById('list'); //found in events\new.html.erb

function addParticipant(){

    var name = document.getElementById('colleague-select').textContent; //gets :full_name of selected Customer
    var entry = document.createElement('li'); //creates new list element within ordered list 'list'
    entry.appendChild(document.createTextNode(name)); //adds :full_name to list element
    List.appendChild(entry); //adds list element to ordered list

}
```

**I have substituted the code within `'addParticipant()'` for `alert('hello')` and it worked fine without redirection**, so what in my javascript code is causing the problem? Any help will be much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: try to add "#" in src <input type="image" src="#" onclick="addParticipant()">

Comment: do you mean add it to the beginning? I tried that and it still redirects..

Comment: sorry, <%= link_to(image_tag('image_path'), "#"), :onclick => "addParticipant()" %> try this rails link

Comment: rubymine isn't liking that syntax for some reason, it's highlighting around :onclick saying "expecting %>, ;, or <%= or end of line" ?

Comment: are you sure you have the comma before `:onclick`?

Comment: definitely. I found a way around it by making it a button and setting its type to "button". Thanks

Comment: try to add `:remote => true`

Answer (score 1):

an alert dialog popup stops default click behaviour, but your code does not.

You will need to do that explicitly:

```
function addParticipant(e) {
  ...
  e.preventDefault();
}
```

Comment: can you think of any other reason this could still be happening? I'm confused as to how it would know which page to send to and how it would get its address

Comment: what do you have inside renderColCal(this)?